# cannot server static files with nginx in django

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, django-staticfiles

I am running a django with nginx as a web server. After configuration its seems that I am always getting 404 for static files. Here is my configurtaion

> base.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_files'),
]
```

> nginx.conf

```
    upstream django {
        server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock;
    }


    # configuration of the server
    server {
        listen  5000;
        server_name server localhost:5000;  address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;   

      location /static {
        alias /Users/del/projects/app-backend/static/; 
      }

      location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
        autoindex on;
        root /Users/del/projects/app-backend/static/; 
      }

      location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/del/perso/django/library/uwsgi;

       } 
    }
```

I have made sure to run `python manage.py collectstatic`, and the files are actually generated under `/static/` folder

Comment: did you used collectstatic?

Comment: yes, i did and i have already written that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have guessed what should work for nginx, but don't understand how alias and root work:

`root` sets the parent directory for the location. A physical directory with the same name must exist in the parent directory:

```
root    /var/www
directory     |----- /static
file                    |----- image.jpg
```

`location /static` with `root /var/www` will now serve files from `/var/www/static`. The URL `http://example.com/static/image.jpg` will serve `/var/www/static/image.jpg`.

Same structure, but `location /s` with `alias /var/www/static` will now serve files from `/var/www/static`. The URL `http://example.com/s/image.jpg` will serve `/var/www/static/image.jpg`.

So your simple config would be:

```
server {
    root /var/www; # Set root at server level

    location /static {
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
    }
 }
```

I don't know what you need the regex for. If you use Django's `static` tag in your templates consistently, there is no need to match "/images" and so forth.

And finally, since `static` is in the regex and regex patterns have priority over string matches, all your references to `/static/` in the URL are being looked for in `app-backend/static/static`.